# Require input field to be filled only if one of multiple select options selected

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with a SELECT and TEXT (and others) input.  The SELECT has two options.  One of the options requires that a date is added to the text box, the other doesn't need a date.

I need to find a way to require the TEXT input be completed (which is a jquery datepicker) if one of the form options is selected, but not require it with the other.

The form ...

```
<input class="ml-text" type="text" name="descriptive_title" size="45" placeholder="Required ..." value="<? echo $doc_title; ?>"required>
        <br><br>
        <label class="title">Upload Type</label>
        <select class= "ml-select" name="upload_type">
                <option value="cutting_list">Cutting List</option>
                <option value="site_instruction">Extra Works</option>
                </select>
    <input class="ml-text" type="text" size="22" name="date_required" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date Required">
```

I tried to do it with headers on the page that processes the form, but as with all headers, particularly using two on the same page it seems to be grabbing those first before doing anything else.

I tried ...

```
if($upload_type == 'cutting_list' && !isset($POST['date_required'])){
            $desc_title = str_replace(' ', '_', $descriptive_title);
            header( "Location: ../workflow/workflow.php?error=no_date&doc_title=$desc_title&department=$department");
    }
else {
     .... do everything else
header( "Location: ../workflow/workflow.php ");
}
```

With the idea that if the upload type was a cutting list, but the date POST not set (also tried !empty) then it would return to the form with an error, but if those conditions weren't met, would carry on with the script and go back to the form, now submitted without the error stuff in the header.

Just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check with javascript/jQuery the value of the `select`
(https://api.jquery.com/change/) and if it is the one with the required datetime you could add the `required` (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute) attribute to the `input`

Small sample script, which will set the input to required if the value `1` is selected.

```html
<html>
<body>
<select onchange="if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == '1') {document.getElementById('myinput').setAttribute('required', '');} else {document.getElementById('myinput').removeAttribute('required')}">
  <option value=''>none</option>
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
 </select>
<input type='text' id='myinput'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would be the logical way to go, however I'm not skilled with JavaScript, so would be back asking another question about how to write the code! :(

Comment: See my updated answer, it uses plain javascript, so no need for jQuery.

Comment: @Pit - why do you add the `javascript:` text to the `onchange` ? The browser should always interpret this as javascript, so there shouldn't be a need for that.

Comment: Actually I 'stole' most of the the code as I practically never use plain javascript, but your right it is not needed. Perhaps for backwards compatibility? I removed it from the answer.

Comment: Top man,thank you.  On further reading I could have just added ob_start(); to beginning and ob_flush(); to end of the PHP form handler.  Tried and works well to ensure the whole page is processed properly before anything happens.  Your answer used in the project though!